# Multiplying a number without using * operator

Tags: java, c++

I was going through a programming class and was asked this tricky question which was left unanswered till the end of the class.

**Question**:

How can I multiply any input(Float,int etc)  by 7, 
`without using the` `*` operator 
in `TWO steps`.

If anyone can give me the answer for this question with the explanation , that would be very helpful.

> **With TWO STEPS I mean suppose you are running a loop (i=0;i<7;i++) in
>   that case number of steps will be >2, also TYPE CONVERSION,
>   DIVISION,ADDITION etc ( Counts for steps ).**

Comment: I'm guessing bit shifting is supposed to be part of this, but that shouldn't work overly well with floating-point bits.

Comment: you could use the `/` operator

Comment: What counts as a step? Also, what kind of correctness is expected?

Comment: +1 for @R.MartinhoFernandes and what's the input number?

Comment: What's regarded a "step"? how many steps are there in int `i = i<<3 - i;` ?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes like if u put it in the loop, in that case every time the loop is entered , it counts as steps .

Comment: @Aki Suihkonen: Does this work with float input?

Comment: @MarcoForberg, No, it won't. This seemed like the sort of question where bit shifting would be a likely in-class trick until I saw the float part.

Comment: any specific reason for solving in 2 steps?

Comment: It would seem to me that `a + a + a + a + a + a + a` is just one step; at least, it's a single expression.

Comment: @chris no matter the teacher challenged or what, there should be reason behind it, be it performance, memory limits etc...., it helps suggest a good solution,

Comment: @ay89, I think it's just one of those "makes you think" questions, but yes, some reason for it definitely helps people to see why they might have to think like this in the first place.

Comment: i / (1.0/7.0); isn't a two-step procedure, as it consists of one division and two type conversions. f / (1.0f/7.0f) is OTOH a one step trick (as the compiler performs constant folding). exp( x + log(7)); is 3-4 step sequence.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov this question was just to identify other ways (out of the box) which can be used to do a very simple calculation.

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." (q) the FAQ on "Ask Question" page. Not riddles.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov ofcourse it is a practical question with very much PRACTICAL answers.

Comment: Then please describe a PRACTICAL, as in HAPPENED IN REAL LIFE scenario, when you suddenly lost * in any programming language and now have to invent new ways to multiply.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov come on man practical means something which is do-able , i have mentioned very clearly in my question that this question occured during a programming class. and as far as practicality goes there are always different ways of doing /solving an issue, and one should be aware of them. I very much appreciate your thinking though.

Comment: @Oleg when the 'multiply' button on my calculator broke.

Comment: @ColonelPanic LOL good 1 mate .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming `float x` or `double x` is defined in the scope. Then I see the following possibilities to multiply it by 7 without using the `*` operator:

In C++, you can use the standard functors (first step: create functor, second step: call functor):

```
x = std::multiplies<float>()(x, 7.0f);  // if x is a float
x = std::multiplies<double>()(x, 7.0);  // if x is a double
```

Or only use division (Since the compiler already evaluates `1.0 / 7.0`, this is only one step):

```
x = x / (1.0f / 7.0f);  // if x is a float
x = x / (1.0  / 7.0);   // if x is a double
```

Or use the `*=` operator (technically, it's not the `*` operator, but it's only one single step):

```
x *= 7.0f;  // if x is a float
x *= 7.0;   // if x is a double
```

Or use addition in the logarithmic scale (this is not to be taken very serious, as well as this requires more than two "steps"):

```
x = exp(log(x) + log(7.0));
```

Another option is to use an assembly instruction, but I don't want to write that now, since it's overly complicated.

If `x` is an integer, bit shifting is another option, but *not recommended*:

```
x = (x << 3) - x;   // (x * 8) - x
```

Comment: I like the logarithm solution. I would definitely pick that one. See where applying one logarithmic identity can get you.

Comment: I believe `x = x / (1.0 / 7.0)` (or `(1.0f / 7.0f))` will likely be optimized into a multiplication operation in most compilers, so there should not be any performance issues. Though you need to **take care of integer division** if the type is `int`, just beware **not** to write `(1 / 7)`.

Comment: If the type of `x` is `int`, I guess it would be calculated as `double` (since `1.0 / 7.0`) is a double, and afterwards converted back to `int`, so I guess it would be equal to `x * 7`, though not sure.

Comment: I don't know what OP is looking for, but I would consider 1-3 to be "cheating" because they call a multiply operation. I'm not sure the implementation of exp and log in 4, but if they call a multiply operation, I would think that's "cheating" as well. Thus, #5 is the one I like the best. I think the easiest solution is the for loop Aswin provides, though.

Comment: The log solution is broken when x<=0.

Answer (score 17):

You could simply use division by a seventh:

```
x / (1.0 / 7)
```

Whether this counts as "two steps" is entirely up to your definition.

Comment: This will divide by zero.

Comment: Erm, no. Dividing by 0 doesn't really help.

Comment: I meant it as mathematics, rather than C++. But sure.

Comment: In case it matters: in Java for integer types this behaves differently on overflow from multiplying by 7. In C++ for integer types overflow has UB, so it's not defined by the standard whether it behaves the same or differently.

Comment: To simplify, we can precalcuate 1.0 / 7.0 = 0.14285714285 so your code becomes x/0.14285714285.  This should be one step by most definitions.

Comment: @emory: The compiler would already do that for you of course

Comment: Doesn't the 1.0 automatically force other members to double? I remember it being that way in java, and definitely know it to be so in C#. Can't speak for c++ though.

Answer (score 7):

add it

```
//initialise s as the number to be multiplied
 sum=0
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    sum+=s
```

Comment: in loop it will count for 7 steps.

Comment: what do you mean by steps exactly?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, Look in the OP comments.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh you asked for two step ans not for 2 statement ans

Answer (score 4):

In C, the following hack should work for floats stored in [IEEE single precision floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format):

```c
#include <stdint.h>

float mul7 (float x) {
    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t i;
    } u;
    u.f = x;
    u.i += (3 << 23);  /* increment exponent by 3 <=> multiply by 8 */
    return u.f - x;    /* 8*x - x == 7*x */
}
```

That's two steps (one integer addition, one float subtraction), sort of, depending on what you count as a step.  Given that C++ is more or less backwards-compatible with C, I believe a similar trick should be possible there too.

Note, however, that this hack generally won't give correct results for [subnormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number), infinite or NaN inputs, nor for inputs so large in magnitude that multiplying them by 8 would overflow.

Adjusting the code to use doubles instead of float is left as an exercise for the reader.  (Hint: the magic number is 52.)

Comment: The endianness of the platform must also be checked. On big endian machine the line `u.i += (3 << 23);` becomes simply `u.i += 3;`.

Comment: Therefore it would be better to use `union { float f; uint8_t i[4]; }` and `u.i[3] += 3` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You may also do the following for integers:

```
( x<< 3) - x
```

Comment: doesn't work for float

Comment: @HazemEl-Raffiee yeah,bit shift does not work for float or double, updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define "two steps"...

```
float result = 0.0f;
float input = 3.14f;
int times = 7;

// steps

while (times--)
    result += input;
```

**Edit**: dividing by (1 / 7) won't work with `int` type. Also in some languages for it to work with float type, you'd have to mark them as floats:

```
result = input / (1.0f / 7.0f);
```

Comment: but doesn't that become `input power 7?`

Comment: You're totally right, corrected. :) Thanks.

Comment: result should be initialized to 0, not 1.

Comment: @fgrieu, you're right. It was 1, because I was multiplying, not adding before. See Aswin's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
// String num = "10";
// int num = 10;
float num = 10;

BigDecimal bigD = new BigDecimal(num);
BigDecimal seven = new BigDecimal(7);
System.out.println(seven.multiply(bigD));
```

You could use the `BigDecimal` & its `multiply` method. Works for pretty much everything.

Answer (score -3):

Add 7 by x times.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    result = result+7;
```

Comment: The OP asked for a way to multiply by 7 not to add 70.